# How to Arrange Dataframe values Based on the Occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a Dataframe having the following column values:

```
Name    |   Subject     |   Mark
------------------------------------
Daniel  |   Maths       |   95
Sam     |   Science     |   98
Nathan  |   English     |   90
Hobbs   |   Social      |   85
Shaw    |   Language    |   90
Daniel  |   Social      |   99
Shaw    |   Science     |   75
Nathan  |   Maths       |   99
Sam     |   Language    |   70
Hobbs   |   Language    |   90
Shaw    |   Social      |   90
Nathan  |   Social      |   85
Daniel  |   English     |   90
Nathan  |   Science     |   85
Hobbs   |   English     |   85
Nathan  |   Language    |   90
Daniel  |   Science     |   98
Sam     |   Social      |   85
Shaw    |   Maths       |   95
Daniel  |   Language    |   95
Sam     |   Maths       |   99
Hobbs   |   Science     |   99
Sam     |   English     |   75
Shaw    |   English     |   90
Hobbs   |   Maths       |   85
```

I need to create a code which would transform the dataframe into the following:

```
Name    |   Subject 1   |   Mark 1  |   Subject 2   |   Mark 2  |   Subject 3   |   Mark 3  |   Subject 4   |   Mark 4  |   Subject 5   |   Mark 5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Daniel  |   Maths       |   95      |   Social      |   99      |   English     |   90      |   Science     |   98      |   Language    |   95
Sam     |   Science     |   98      |   Language    |   70      |   Social      |   85      |   Maths       |   99      |   English     |   75
Nathan  |   English     |   90      |   Maths       |   99      |   Social      |   85      |   Science     |   85      |   Language    |   90
Hobbs   |   Social      |   85      |   Language    |   90      |   English     |   85      |   Science     |   99      |   Maths       |   85
Shaw    |   Language    |   90      |   Science     |   75      |   Social      |   90      |   Maths       |   95      |   English     |   90
```

What is done here is that for each name, the subjects are arranged in the order of their occurrence in the original dataframe in columns. What python code can achieve this?

Edit#1: There are other columns like Reg.No, Class, etc. which is just unique value for each student. So I need a solution which has the above mentioned columns along with these.

Comment: Have you tried starting with grouping by 'Name'? Or maybe a pivot would work.

Comment: Does *everyone* have the same number of Subjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
index = flatten([["Subject " +str(i), "Mark "+ str(i) ] for i in range(1,6)])
for item in df.groupby('Name'):
    l = (item[1]).iloc[:,1:].values.tolist()
    flat_list = flatten(l)
    s = pd.Series(data = flat_list, index= index, name = item[0])
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, s], axis=1)
    
new_df = new_df.T
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pivot`:

```
In [1415]: df.pivot('Name', 'Subject', 'Mark')
Out[1415]: 
Subject  English  Language  Maths  Science  Social
Name                                              
Daniel        90        95     95       98      99
Hobbs         85        90     85       99      85
Nathan        90        90     99       85      85
Sam           75        70     99       98      85
Shaw          90        90     95       75      90
```

Comment: This is not the expected result, but it does make sense to have data in such format

Comment: @RobertAxe Yes, pandas provides `pivot` api to convert the date in above format. Which is kind of cleaner and readable than what OP actually wants.

Comment: This is really helpful, but I need the solution as I have mentioned in the question, as this is the requirement from my Organization.

Comment: Actually there are several other columns in the original data, like Reg. No, Class, etc.. The above mentioned columns should show along with these columns..

Comment: @MujeeburRahman you should add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

A little convoluted, but should do:

```
>>> (df.groupby('Name', sort=False)[['Subject', 'Mark']]
      .apply(lambda x: x.stack().reset_index(drop=True))
      .rename(columns=lambda x: f"{['Subject', 'Mark'][x%2]} {x//2+1}")
    )
       Subject 1  Mark 1 Subject 2  Mark 2 Subject 3  Mark 3 Subject 4  \
Name                                                                     
Daniel     Maths      95    Social      99   English      90   Science   
Sam      Science      98  Language      70    Social      85     Maths   
Nathan   English      90     Maths      99    Social      85   Science   
Hobbs     Social      85  Language      90   English      85   Science   
Shaw    Language      90   Science      75    Social      90     Maths   

        Mark 4 Subject 5  Mark 5  
Name                              
Daniel      98  Language      95  
Sam         99   English      75  
Nathan      85  Language      90  
Hobbs       99     Maths      85  
Shaw        95   English      90
```

**EDIT:**

If you want `n` subjects:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> (df.groupby('Name', sort=False)[['Subject', 'Mark']]
      .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:n].stack().reset_index(drop=True))
      .rename(columns=lambda x: f"{['Subject', 'Mark'][x%2]} {x//2+1}")
    )

       Subject 1  Mark 1 Subject 2  Mark 2 Subject 3  Mark 3
Name                                                        
Daniel     Maths      95    Social      99   English      90
Sam      Science      98  Language      70    Social      85
Nathan   English      90     Maths      99    Social      85
Hobbs     Social      85  Language      90   English      85
Shaw    Language      90   Science      75    Social      90
```

Comment: Can I modify it as to limit the number of subjects? For e.g: I need the top 3 subjects, so the columns should stoop till Subject 3 and Mark 3. Can this criteria be added to this answer?

Comment: Sorry bro, but I got an error stating ```Series.name must be a hashable type```.